# What are the inputs to the truffle Txn?

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle

I am testing truffle now and I want to know more about what it deploys and how. It seems to use two txns. I have some results -

```
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Deploying CA12...
  ... 0x2d0f35d5802958bb5d96f162f3d2e0b0354946081cf6119b9b13d40994e1c054
  CA12: 0x7abf846141964365f2f817238e4038ab70d419ea
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0x910576d8c200629f0b684ba903962a52e662d58eb8b41ec5c9c9618bb9583c46
Saving artifacts...

> eth.getTransaction("0x2d0f35d5802958bb5d96f162f3d2e0b0354946081cf6119b9b13d40994e1c054")
{
  blockHash: "0x66ee27a4beec501915e955b0db170f2f1f807bea07ea1bb484e71c7c080d0fd5",
  blockNumber: 115386,
  from: "0x46fb9a22689c4a4bfb494baeafbb8b2993725305",
  gas: 4712388,
  gasPrice: 100000000000,
  hash: "0x2d0f35d5802958bb5d96f162f3d2e0b0354946081cf6119b9b13d40994e1c054",
  input: "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",
  nonce: 283,
  r: "0xb82dc037511e4ee7b8c709d21c5cb4be8520513b3d8d188245db22116ee961e5",
  s: "0x25909e9a3c182d50c6ef447be88f0e98d30c449b7ffd4e02d8b17091290f9215",
  to: null,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x2b694",
  value: 0
}
> eth.getTransaction("0x910576d8c200629f0b684ba903962a52e662d58eb8b41ec5c9c9618bb9583c46")
{
  blockHash: "0xc1061ec3764d723254ce30707898ead8f48b0c177dc758a3b2cb98cb26bb03c3",
  blockNumber: 115388,
  from: "0x46fb9a22689c4a4bfb494baeafbb8b2993725305",
  gas: 4712388,
  gasPrice: 100000000000,
  hash: "0x910576d8c200629f0b684ba903962a52e662d58eb8b41ec5c9c9618bb9583c46",
  input: "0xfdacd5760000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002",
  nonce: 284,
  r: "0xc67dc71c347361464738a87fa0de75e1ce4a334350a1ced6ea10abea50563b4a",
  s: "0x1cacb3bf0a873f8d0ba5565932fc121ae9323d00d25a63c1636e260b4fd233ba",
  to: "0xa3c4c30d50fdc6824a8a612c65d6e97dfd4d2a0e",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x2b693",
  value: 0
}
>
```

The input to the first hash is I assume byte code from the compile. It has a lot of FFFF which looks like inefficiency to me. But what is the second input (in the second txn) -

```
0xfdacd5760000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
```

That is the migration part I think.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the second transaction, you have to take a look at `Migrations.sol` which comes with truffle. It's used to store checkpoints for migrations. In the case of error you can restart your migration at this step.

The relevant function from `Migrations.sol` is this one:

```
function setCompleted(uint completed) restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
}
```

First four bytes (fdacd576) of the transaction are the signature of the method and 0...02 is the parameter, which is step 2 of your migration process.

```
0xfdacd5760000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
```

Comment: I deleted the 1_ ... file because the Migations.sol did not work properly at a hackathon I was at. I deleted that too on my desktop. Everything seems to run still. I did not really know what the Migrations.sol did. I also deleted the Migrations.sol file.

Comment: It could be that your step 1 already ran successfully. Try deleting the build folder and rerunning truffle migrate. Does it still work?

Comment: I will try and add the Migration.sol later. I do not want to risk that the system stops working now. But it does work without Migrations.sol. I will check into that contract more later.

Comment: You can also check if you have Migrations.json in the build folder.

Comment: I checked, the Migrations.sol file exists and also the json version but I deleted the 1_... file. That did not seem to make any difference.

Comment: I guess truffle will skip sending the migration tx, if there is no Migrations contract in the build folder(?) But if it has one, it will use it (I assume).

Comment: I will test it all later with different combinations of Migrations.sol.